# Google Apps Script: How to acess an array values from a submit function in a checkBox list?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is a very basic question (I'm a novice in GAS and JS). I have the code bellow. When a use it, I'd like that the `submit` function returns the `itemsSelected`. But, since it's returning `app`, how can I acess `itemsSelected` values from submit function?

```
var fact_list = ["He planted a tree", "She visited a nursing home", "They have donated books to the library"];

function showList() {
    var mydoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');
    // Store the number of items in the array (fact_list)
    panel.add(app.createHidden('checkbox_total', fact_list.length));
    // add 1 checkbox + 1 hidden field per item 
    for(var i = 0; i < fact_list.length; i++){
      var checkbox = app.createCheckBox().setName('checkbox_isChecked_'+i).setText(fact_list[i]);
      var hidden = app.createHidden('checkbox_value_'+i, fact_list[i]);
      panel.add(checkbox).add(hidden);
    }
    var handler = app.createServerHandler('submit').addCallbackElement(panel);
    panel.add(app.createButton('Submit', handler));
    app.add(panel);
    mydoc.show(app);
}

function submit(e){
  var numberOfItems = e.parameter.checkbox_total;
  var itemsSelected = [];
  // for each item, if it is checked / selected, add it to itemsSelected
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++){
    if(e.parameter['checkbox_isChecked_'+i] == 'true'){
      itemsSelected.push(e.parameter['checkbox_value_'+i]);
    }
  }
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('panel').clear().add(app.createLabel(itemsSelected));
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to use it?  In another function? How about storing it in ScripProperties for example...

Comment: Hi, @Serge insas, you're a kind of Dungeon Master in SoF! I'd like to use it in another function! (not in ScriptProperties).

Comment: (the above comment was intended to be a funny compliment =)

Comment: He he...:-)  that's how I understood it :-) thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the function `submit(e)` is a handler function called by the submit button, every value that you define in that function will not be available to any other function unless you create a second handler in this submit function with another event etc... (which is obviously not the case here).

So the only way to keep that value available to another function is to store it "somewhere" where it will be available for the other functions.

From there the choice is yours... You mentioned in the comment you don't wat to use scriptProperties, but you can use scriptDb or userProperties or even the spreadsheet in which you are working but it has to be somewhere and it can't be in the UI in the example you show unless you have another event in this UI that would call the third function we are talking about.

In this case (*and only in this last case*) you can use a `hidden widget` or an invisible `textBox` to assign a stringified value of your array and get it back in the handler using the classical `e.parameter.varName` but this doesn't seem to be your use case.

Hoping I'm being clear enough....
If not then feel free to mention it.

**EDIT :** *just a note :* You are using a `Label` to show the value of `itemsSelected` . That's not the best choice since Labels can't have names , meaning we can't get a value from them even if we had a handler and an event... Labels are definitely 'one way' to show values. If it where a textBox you could use some kind of handler to trigger another function and retrieve the `itemsSelected` value.

Comment: Yes, totally clear! I read in your profile that you are self-taught and learned GAS alone. This is inspiring! Thanks again!